# Merge working time periods

Tags: code-golf, date, array

You have an array of working time period pairs (from, till) received from user input and written according  24-hour clock format convention.
   You have to merge these periods if the intersect each other.

For example, if you have (10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14) you should merge them into (10,14). 
   Also (23, 0) and (0, 1) should be merged into (23, 1).

UPDATE:

@dmckee Let assume that the set of pairs like (10:00, 12:00) is the valid input.

@dude We don't consider Sundays and holidays so all merges should be performed for the common twenty-four hours range.

@steven-rumbalski  The result of (0,8), (8,16), (16,0) may be any (x,x) pair, for example, (00:00,00:00).

**Example 1**

Input

```
(09:00,12:00),(11:00,13:00),(17:00,19:00)
```

Output

```
(09:00,13:00),(17:00,19:00)
```

---

**Example 2**

Input

```
(00:00,08:00),(08:00,16:00),(16:00,00:00)
```

Output

```
(00:00)
```

Comment: Is `(10,12)` a valid input, or should it be `(10:00, 12:00)` or something similar? Likewise, what is the correct format for the output? Also each challenge should specify what the metric is (i.e. we don't only do [code-golf] or even default to it).

Comment: Because one work shift can spill over from one day into the next [as (23,0)+(0,1) =(23,1) appears to show], shouldn't we be keeping track of the days in the workweek also?  If Sunday is not a work day, it would seem that (23,1), starting Sunday Evening and going to 1 am Monday, would not count.  However, from Monday to Tuesday, it would be counted.

Comment: What should the result of `(0,8), (8,16), (16,0)` be?

Comment: In the future, maybe post your spec to the sandbox on meta first to get feedback before you post. This could have been a great question with a little more work.

Comment: @TimSeguine thank you for your suggestion, I did not know about this opportunity!

Answer (score 1):

## Python (198 chars)

```
r=[]
p=r.append
l=r+sorted(a<b and (a,b)or p((0,b))or(a,24)for a,b in input())
r[:]=[]
a,b=l[0]
for c,d in l[1:]:
 if c>b:p((a,b));a,b=c,d
 elif b<d:b=d
if b>23:b=a and r.pop(0)[1]
p((a,b))
print r
```

Example:

```
> python merge.py
(10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14)
[(10, 14)]
> python merge.py
(23,0),(0,1)
[(23, 1)]
> python merge.py
(0,8), (8,16), (16,0)
[(0, 0)]
```